# Getting Image Dimentions ONLY from a folder inside another folder which is in Assets saving maximum Memory in Android

Tags: android, memory-management

I need to get image dimensions only from a folder inside another folder which is in Assets folder.
I have tried some codes but I am unable to save memory i.e I don't want to load the image into memory I only want to get the dimensions of all files in a folder.
Here is the code I am using but this is not memory efficient I don't want to load the bitmaps.

```
private void getFileNames()
{
    AssetManager assetManager = mCxt.getAssets();
    InputStream bitmap;
    Bitmap bit;
    Log.d("Jawad"," in Function");
    // To get names of all files inside the "Files" folder
    try {
        String[] files = assetManager.list(mFolferPath);

        Log.d("Jawad"," Length "+files.length);
        for(int i=0; i<files.length; i++)
        {
            if(files[i].contains(".png") ||files[i].contains(".jpg"))
            {
                Log.d("Jawad","" +files[i]);
                bitmap=assetManager.open(mFolferPath+"/"+files[i]);
                bit=BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap);
                Log.d("Jawad",""+ " ," +bit.getWidth() + " , " + bit.getHeight());
                bitmap = null;
                bit.recycle();
                bit = null;
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        Log.d("Jawad"," "+e1);
    }
}
```

mFolferPath = gfx/decoration/biscuits

This code is giving me the dimensions but again the problem is I don't want to load them into memory.

Comment: try using decodeStream(InputStream is, Rect outPadding, BitmapFactory.Options opts) where pass  with inJustDecodeBounds = true for option

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get only the dimensions of an image decode it with BitmapFactory.Options.inJustDecodeBounds set to true.

```
BitmapFactory.Options Bitmp_Options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
Bitmp_Options.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bitmap, null, options);

int currentImageHeight = Bitmp_Options.outHeight;
int currentImageWidth = Bitmp_Options.outWidth;
```

[see here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/BitmapFactory.Options.html#inJustDecodeBounds)